# image updated on page works fine only after clearing the browser history in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page named sample.aspx.
This page reads image from user.and saved details shows to the user using a table....When the user click on the edit button it shows all the details back to the fields(including image).Update works fine for me.But The page shows the updated image only after clearing history of browser.
How to solve this?pls help me
Thanks and regards
Nijisha k C

Comment: You should really post the code and script you are using for uploading, without which its hard to tell

Comment: It may have connection to Page refresh than browser history. After update you need to refresh your table with latest image.

Comment: Just to clear out, Browser history cleanup removes cache, saved data etc, that makes the page reload and you see updated page, Isn't it want you are missing? to reload the data after updating image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the image to be cached you can attach a random query string (server time might be a good idea) to the image. This will make sure the browser always checks for updates:

```
<img src="picture.jpg?123415215125">
```

Comment: Thank You Mr JP. You are right.It works..Appreciate your fast response.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the Browser Cache than anything to do with .NET. If the image SRC is the same when revisiting a webpage before the cache expired date the browser will just grab the image from the local browser cache rather than the server

That said its common practice in this case is to update a parameter on the Image SRC usually by assigning a timestamp.

Use something like this:

```
newImage.src = "image.jpg?parameter=" + new Date();
```

To produce:

```
  <img src="image.jpg?parameter=1436422632">
```